# What is the easiest way to convert an existing project to Sass?

Tags: css, sass

I have recently jumped on the Sass bandwagon - and like most people I had a "where have you been my whole life?" moment. I have a couple of BIG projects going that have to be maintained pretty regularly that I would like to use Sass for (it would make my life a lot easier).

What am I up against here? Transcribing all of the existing CSS to Sass (or SCSS) by hand? Or is there any easier way?

**Edit**

This is a question of best practices. I have found a handful of options before posting this - but I would like to know what is generally accepted or recommended.

Comment: SASS or SCSS..? SCSS should be compatible?

Comment: @Petah I understand that it may be compatible - but I would like everything to be uniform, rather than a garbled mess of CSS and SCSS. I apologize for my lack of clarity, I'll update my question.

Comment: And you think there is an automatic tool to convert your garbled mess of CSS into SCSS? GIGO. Best option is just to slowly start doing it piece by piece.

Comment: @Petah That is what I was afraid of. I didn't necessarily think that there was a good easy way out, I was just hoping.

Comment: "Best practices" questions aren't really suitable for SO.  Do you have a specific question about converting a specific piece of code?

Comment: Also just incase you haven't seen, checkout http://compass-style.org/ and http://susy.oddbird.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the `.scss` syntax then the simplest thing to do is rename your `.css` files to `.scss` and start compiling. Tools like [sass-convert](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/#id2) or [css2sass](http://css2sass.heroku.com/) (as mentioned in @SharkofMirkwood's answer) can help, but depending on the size of the project that you're starting with, it may be wiser to re-factor on demand.

In my experience, using a tool is OK for small projects but won't actually give you much advantage over curating your own solution. The tools aren't going to help you learn the metalanguage and they may not produce optimal results in the first place (again: especially for larger projects).

Comment: This is what I was afraid of, but I think you are probably right. I may just make the conversion a weekend project. It will probably be good to really dig through through the old CSS again anyway to give it a facelift.

Comment: Trust me, you'll be thankful for it later -- the deep dive is worthwhile, and the Sass user community is very helpful.

Comment: css2sass is ideal for compressing a vendor's lazy CSS framework into chunks. What it outputs isn't pretty but it gets the process of a real conversion off on the right foot.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like [sass-convert](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/#id2) or [css2sass](http://css2sass.heroku.com/)?

Comment: Yes - css2sass is something I came across earlier but wasn't sure if it was something that people had used or recommended. My question is one of best practices rather than just what I CAN do.

Comment: Yes, now I understand. Seems you got your answer anyway, so good luck with the conversion.